# Transforming a of system of differential equations of variable coefficients into system of constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, change-of-variable

I want to change the following system into a system of constant coefficients.

$x_1'=(1+\cos2t)x_1+(1-2\sin2t)x_2$,

$x_2'=-(1+2\sin2t)x_1+(1-2\sin2t)x_2$

In the question itself, they have given a hint to use the transformation below to convert it into a system with constant coefficients.

$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos t&\sin t\\
-\sin t&\cos t
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2
\end{bmatrix}$

But I am unable to reach the final system. Can someone help me with this?
I have tried to write the new equations in $y_1$ and $y_2$ by using the existing equations. Like I wrote $x_1=\cos ty_1 +\sin ty_2 $ and similarly $x_2$. I tried differentiating it. By substituting the given system, I thought it would reduce to a system with constant coefficients. But it didn't. I tried the other way around, also. I wrote $y_1$ and $y_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then tried to construct a new system. It also didn't work out.

Comment: @Moo I have tried to write the new equations in $y_1$ and $y_2$ by using the existing equations. Like I wrote $x_1=costy_1 +sinty_2 $ and similarly x_2. I tried differentiating it. By substituting the given system, I thought it would reduce to a system with constant coefficients. But it didn't. I tried the other way around, also. I wrote $y_1$ and $y_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then tried to construct a new system. It also didn't work out.

Comment: Are you sure there is 3 times sine and only one cosine? If that correction applies, can you go complex and use $z=x_1+ix_2$ to get a first order linear DE in $z$ with complex coefficients?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry I didn't get that complex argument you made; please elaborate a little more. This is the question given; When I tried, I also felt a little weird cause there are three sine terms.

Comment: Just from the constant coefficients you get $z'=(1-i)z+...$. However there would have to be several changes to get the remaining terms into the form of a complex product like $(\cos(2t)-i\sin(2t))z$, so this idea is probably wrong. One typo is possible, changes in 3 or more places are unlikely to indicate an error.